# Image import errors (csv)

Tags: import, csv, magento2.3.1

I'm trying to import 500 images (at a time, 13000 total) using a csv.

I keep getting the following error:

> Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external
>   resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s).

The images are in var/import, and the permissions are **set to 777**

The file validates without any issues, but errors out once I hit the import button.
Does anyone know how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the directories in pub/media are writable as well?

Comment: yes. I ended up moving the files to pub/media/import, and most of them worked. Some of them still threw errors, but it's a more managable number.